# Servers syncronization Linux Centos

Tags: centos, mysql, amazon-web-services, rsync, synchronization

I need to synchronize the data in MySQL Database from another server running same application in another Location. How to do the synchronization ? Thankyou in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements MySQL replication or MySQL clustering will likely be what you want.

Comment: How to do that , since i am new to these things i need details to do those things. If you have any link . Please Provide .

Comment: @BhuwanBhandari - There is a lot of documentation and discussion about replication.  This forum is good for short answers, not for volumes of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have the client in the other Location remotely access the MySQL server in the primary location.

Comment: Cannot do that because of security reasons :)

Comment: @BhuwanBhandari - Please elaborate on 'security'.  You could connect using SSL.

Comment: We cannot let our vendors use our database directly